# Return an empty object Java Spring Boot REST

Tags: spring-boot

I'm writing a dto class containing the information of a user

```
public class User {
    private String firstName;
    
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

I'd receive this JSON object if I do GET api/v1/user/1

```
{
  firstName: John,
  lastName: Kennedy
}
```

But when the firstName and the lastName are null, I want to receive an empty object like:

```
{}
```

How would you do technically on Spring Boot in order to receive such empty object in Json format?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

You could try to annotate your class with:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an empty object `{ }` and empty request is not valid for you, you can create an auxiliar class called `EmptyObject` or something similar:

```java
@JsonSerialize
public class EmptyObject {

}
```

And into your controller:

```java
return user.getFirstName() == null && user.getLastName() == null ?  
                ResponseEntity.ok(new EmptyObject()) : ResponseEntity.ok(user);
```