# I am getting my message logged but I am not sure why I am getting stack trace along with it

Tags: spring, exception, java-8

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {
//If I am having invalid Employee Id entered my program should throw error
public EmployeeDTO updateEmployeeDto(EmployeeDTO employeeDTO, Long employeeId){
    Optional<Employees> employeeWithId =     Optional.ofNullable(employeesRepo.findByEmployeeId(employeeId));
if(!employeeWithId.isEmpty()){
            Employees employee=employeeWithId.get();
    }
else{
            throw new InvalidEntryException("Entered employee id  was not found");
        }
}
}
```

The above is service class that throws an exception and below is
My Exception class:

```
public class InvalidEntryException extends RuntimeException{
    public InvalidEntryException(String message){

        super(message);
    }
}
```

The message that I am getting in the postman is:

```
"timestamp": "2022-12-19T05:33:03.854+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "com.assetmanagementsystems.ams.exception.InvalidEntryException: Entered employee id  was not found\\r\\n\\tat com.assetmanagementsystems.ams.service.serviceImpl.EmployeeServiceImpl.getEmployeeById(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:64)\\r\\n\\tat com.assetmanagementsystems.ams.controller.EmployeeController.retrieveEmpById(EmployeeController.java:60)java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\\r\\n",
    **"message": "Entered employee id  was not found",**
    "path": "/employees/employee/22"
}
```

Comment: `throw new XXXException` always get stacktrace and Error 500, better design is consider reference `Return an empty object Java Spring Boot REST` ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68727512/return-an-empty-object-java-spring-boot-rest )

Comment: You can create custom exception objects and have it passed as response object. Also, it is recommended to use global exception handlers